# launch arbitrary number of nodes

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to control a swarm of quadcopters. Each quadcopter has a name, and 'launching' a quadcopter involves making a namespace for it and starting up a few nodes. I was wondering if, when using the 'roslaunch' command, I could give an arbitrary number of names as arguments and then make a namespace and include another launch file for every name. I don't think it's possible but I wanted to check.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237891/launch-arbitrary-number-of-nodes/) by [baraki](https://answers.ros.org/users/27261/baraki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible. Check the [roslaunch tips for large projects](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects).

---

Originally posted by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) with karma: 106 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baraki](https://answers.ros.org/users/27261/baraki/) on 2016-06-23**:
I've read through that, and its only solution is to set environment variables. I will would like to run between 1 and 15 quadcopters. Each one has a different name and I want to be able to use different combinations of them. As far as I can tell that page doesn't explain how to do that?

**Comment by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) on 2016-06-23**:
Choosing a subgroup from the group of 15 quadcopters is software/addressing related. That goes beyond of what launch files can do. On launch files you can define addresses and names, you can make sure that all names and addresses are different. You can comment out nodes/quadcotpers not required.